# On Android, app jumps back to default Page on orientation change

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I tested my [Xamarin.Forms](https://xamarin.com/forms) app on iOS and Android and found this difference when I change the orientation of the mobile device:

- On iOS, the app keeps the current page
- On Android, the app seems to restart using the default page (or probably pop all pages except the first one).

Since I've never seen this behavior in another Android app, I'd like to disable it. Moreover, I don't think that this behavior is Android default.

**Which property do I need to set the make the Android target behave as the iOS target?**

Comment: I believe there was a topic on Xamarin Forums about this but I don't know if there was a solution. Since the forms seem to bind to a single activity I would start from seeing if you can save the page type/info into a bundle and recover the state at restore. Unfortunately the form classes are not serializable at the moment. Quick and dirty fix would be to only support one orientation but that's not a good long term solution. Overall I don't think Xamarin Forms is mature enough yet to replace fully native view controllers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you checked [ActivityAttribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/package-summary.html) of your MainActivity? it should specify [ConfigChanges.Orientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html).

something like this

```
using Android.Content.PM;

[Activity(Label = "%Your app name%", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.ScreenSize)]
```

If ConfigChanges.Orientation is not set OS will recreate Activity on orientation change. And if it set, it indicates that you will manage orientation changing for yourself.